# Catching webhooks from a platform to local

Tags: php, api, laravel-4

I use a platform that allows me to use webhooks. Webhooks will be triggered by an event. So for example, we have the webhook `productUpdate`. This hook will send data to my URL: `mystore.com/url-for-webhook`, and the data will be sent by JSON. So alright, pretty easy to catch, but because I work locally, it's a bit harder. I need to make that webhook think that it's posting to an online website, but then forward it to my local machine.  As such, instead of `mystore.com/url-for-webhook`, it should call `local/url-for-webhook`

Does anybody have a nice solution to make this local available?

Comment: So you need to make your local dev server accessible from the internet?

Comment: Yeah but then i need to open up my router and stuff so i thought maybe there is a bether/other way

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is pretty old, but just in case someone struggles with this like me a few minutes ago, I would suggest to use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) which allow you to create a real URL which will redirect to your local machine ports.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did it a bit different cause im the only one that needs to access those webhooks. I've bought a domain for it and set the DNS to a local server, works like a charm too.

Comment: If you mean that you want to be the only one to access the URL, you can secure the http(s) tunnel : https://ngrok.com/docs#auth Since i'm just testing , i guess ngrok is more than enough for me, but if you need a constant availability, your solution is probably more interesting :)